# How to make each fuction work with dynamically added elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each

I have this script and I would like to make it work with dinamically added elements from database:

```
$( ".select-song li" ).each(
function( intIndex ){
    $( this ).bind (
        "click",
        function(){
          if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
           $(this).removeClass('checked');
          }
          else{
            $(this).addClass('checked');
          }
        }
        );
}
);
```

Elements are added in like this:

```
$('.select-song').append('<li>sth here</li>');
```

I know that I should to use on function but I have no idea how to implement it here.

Comment: Delegate event, no need for each loop  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegating event using `on()`:

```
$(".select-song").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: You don't need the second parameter to `$.toggleClass()`. It behaves like that by default.

Comment: @Phylogenesis indeed you are correct, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event from `.select-song` to `li`:

```
$(".select-song").on("click", "li", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    }
});
```

This way every time you append a newly created `li` in `.select-song`, the event will be bound to it. Remember that it's always best to delegate from the nearest non-dynamic parent. If you delegate from `body` or `document` for example, the performance will not be the same as the event will have to propagate until the matched selector.

Comment: `If you delegate from body or document for example, the performance will not be the same` Is that really matter for a click event? I mean even Chuck Norris cannot be fast enough to click fster than browser can handle it. ;)

Comment: yes, it does matter in large applications where many events are interacting together.

Comment: and it also matters if the element that should receive the event is way down in the DOM tree.

Comment: This is more important for cleaning events when static container is removed e.g, imho